# How to make a quiz in java that plays a sound before each question?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a quiz of musical chords in java and I need to program to play a sound file before asking each question although something is interfering halfway through.

I've tried to use an array list and  fileInputStream player 
here's some code I have tried.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("eminor.mp3");
    Player player = new Player(fileInputStream);
    player.play();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(JavaLayerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    {


    String question1 = "What chord is this?\n"
            + "(a)E minor\n(b)E major\n(c)C minor\n";
    String question2 = "What chord is this?\n"
            + "(a)E Major\n(b)C major\n(c)G major\n";
    String question3 = "What chord is this?\n"
            + "(a)E Major\n(b)C major\n(c)G major\n";
            Question [] questions = {
            new Question(question1,"a")

            {;
    }
    };
    Trial(questions);
    }
            }
    public static void Trial(Question[] questions) {
        int points = 0;
        Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i< questions.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(questions[i].prompt);    
            String answer = keyboardInput.nextLine();
            if(answer.equals(questions[i].answer)) {
                points++;}
                else 
                    System.out.println("Wrong Answer");
                System.out.println(" Your score is " + ""+ points + "/" + questions.length);

    System.out.println("Next Question");



        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("gmajor.mp3");
            Player player = new Player(fileInputStream);
            player.play();
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(JavaLayerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



            public static void Trial2(Question[] questions) {
                int points = 0;
                Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
                for(int i = 0; i< questions.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(questions[i].prompt);    
                    String answer = keyboardInput.nextLine();
                    if(answer.equals(questions[i].answer)) {
                        points++;}
                                else 
                                    System.out.println("Wrong answer");
                    System.out.println("Your score is " + ""+ points + "/" + questions.length);


        }
```

Comment: please also explain what went wrong, or what did not work, or what is the question.

Comment: Yes, what do you mean by, "something is interfering halfway through"? Is the sound just stopping? Does the sound get garbled in some way? Do you get some message? Does the program crash?

Answer (score 0):

You should close your [`FileInputStream.close()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#close()) or even better if you are using java 8 or greater use [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html#suppressed-exceptions)